# Не правильный запрос по двум таблицам, нужно посчитать общее колличество

Tags: mysql, sql

Как посчитать общее колличество заездов лошадей по кличке ?

Мой запрос:

```sql
SELECT 
  COUNT(id_horse_rac) as count 
FROM racing WHERE id_horse_rac = (SELECT id_horse FROM horse WHERE name_horse = 'Звёздачка')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во втором select после id_horse надо добавить as и название

Comment: Простите, не понял, какое именно название ?

Comment: Что выводит у вас? Запрос рабочий.

Comment: Ничего не выводит, должно вывести общее колличество совпадений по имени к примеру "Звёздачка"

Comment: убедитесь, что подзапрос возвращает данные

Comment: покажите название столбцов для первой таблицы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так будет работать)

```
    select 
    count(r.id_horse_rac) as count 
    from horse h
    join racing r on h.id_horse =  r.id_horse_rac
    WHERE h.name_horse = 'Звёздачка'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]